# Error creating bean with name 'HomeController': Lookup method resolution failed

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have some problems when trying to use `@HttpSession` in Spring MVC Controller. I want to cut the first letter of an email from login page to home page with session. To avoid session being null when loading first home page when loaded I used `if` condition but it gives this error:

> Error creating bean with name 'HomeController': Lookup method resolution failed

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping
    @Transactional
    public String Default(@SessionAttribute("email") String email,ModelMap modelMap,HttpSession httpSession) {
        if(httpSession.getAttribute("email") != null) {
            String email =(String) httpSession.getAttribute("email");
            String chacracter = email.substring(0, 1);
            modelMap.addAttribute("chacracter ", chacracter );
        }
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that to be able to inject the HttpSession object directly into Controller method, as shown in your example - this will work as long as the HttpServletRequest object has already been injected into the Controller.

```
@Controller 
@RequestMapping("/") 
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @GetMapping
    @Transactional
    public String Default(@SessionAttribute("email") String email,ModelMap modelMap,HttpSession httpSession) {
        if(httpSession.getAttribute("email") != null) {
            String email =(String) httpSession.getAttribute("email");
            String chacracter = email.substring(0, 1);
            modelMap.addAttribute("chacracter ", chacracter );
        }
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Comment: I added "private HttpServletRequest request" but it still doesn't work.